# How to access to get URL address by name in Django at model file (like {{ url 'urlname' }} at template)

Tags: python, django

Need to access URL by name at model, can't just hardcode it. Need it for error message for a new object creating. Any suggestions?

**Update:** Just need to put url to error message, not reverse

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is not totally clear, but I think you are asking about the [`reverse`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/http/urls/#reverse-resolution-of-urls) function.

Comment: Just need to put url address to error message(ValidationError), not reverse

Comment: I still don't understand. `reverse` is what gives you the URL to put in the message, no?

Answer (score 0):

You can define `get_absolute_url` method in your model and than access it in other model's methods. Check https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/instances/#get-absolute-url

Comment: I need just a link for simple view... I can not hardcode it because it may be located at subdirectory.

Comment: @petriichuk The docs talk about using urls by name also. The second part on using reverse. So you don't have to hardcode it.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use a template tag. You can build one for your model and avoid polluting the model about stuff not related to the domain level and keep the presentation level to the template.

Check the docs here on how add a templatetags your app.: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/howto/custom-template-tags/

Here a snippet of code to use as starting point for your url generation

```
from django import template

register = template.Library()

@register.simple_tag(takes_context=True)
def url_for_object(context, object):
    # you have both the context and the object available to
    # generate your url here
    url = ....
    return url
```

In your template use

```
{% url_for_object my_object %}
```